# Quais os possíveis casos de uso de uma conexão persistente?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, websocket, signalr

Estive lendo sobre SignalR nos últimos dias e basicamente percebi que uma das principais funcionalidades dele é manter uma conexão persistente do servidor com os possíveis *clients* acessando o servidor. Basicamente, ele permite que criemos Hubs e então permite que diversos *clients* (que podem ser tanto Web quanto aplicações .NET) se conectem nesses Hubs e exista uma espécie de conexão contínua.

Eu trabalho com programação pra web desde 2009 e isso é bastante diferente da abordagem tradicional que utiliza o HTTP sem estado. Nesses casos tudo se baseia em requisições e respostas. O client faz uma requisição, a requisição é processada numa pipeline no servidor, o servidor retorna uma resposta e quando a resposta chega no client a conexão com o servidor acabou. Mesmo em aplicações de página única a lógica é essa, só que o servidor passa a servir uma API RESTful.

Por estar acostumado com essa abordagem não estou conseguindo ver quais são as utilidades, os verdadeiros casos de uso de uma conexão persistente. Isso parece ser uma coisa muito útil, mas em quais casos isso realmente é relevante e faz sentido usar?

Sempre vejo o mesmo exemplo do chat, que tem vários clients conectados e eles precisam receber as mensagens dos outros em tempo real. Tudo bem, é um exemplo válido, mas o único caso de uso desse tipo de tecnologia é enviar mensagens do servidor para o *client* sem depender do *client* fazer uma requisição?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pense em um *site* onde as pessoas postam perguntas e respostas, comentam, e fazem outras coisas. Pense que as pessoas vão querer saber quando tem alteração na lista de perguntas, quando alguém modifica algo do seu interesse, se comunica diretamente com a pessoa, ou quando alguém vota e sua reputação muda, quando tem uma fila de moderação para revisar.

Este é um exemplo de *site* que se beneficiaria de uma conexão persistente.

Mas não se apegue a um exemplo concreto. Entenda porque a conexão persistente é útil.

Quando você usa REST a aplicação está requisitando informações do servidor explicitamente. O usuário de uma forma ou de outra determinada o que e quando vai pedir algo para o servidor.

[Websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) são úteis quando você quer o oposto, quer que o servidor se comunique com o cliente. Que ele determine o que e quando mandar alguma informação para o cliente. O importa o que seja:

- *chat*
- redes de interação entre pessoas (social, técnica ou outro tipo)
- jogos
- monitoramentos diversos (equipamentos, mercado financeiro, *feed* de notícias diversas, etc.)
- colaboração entre membros de equipe de trabalho ou estudo
- monitoramento em tempo real do fluxo de utilização do *site* pelos usuários
- atualização baseada em dados externos (GPS por exemplo), etc.

Além disto a comunicação pode ser mais eficiente se usada apropriadamente. Desta forma você trafega só o que realmente é necessário, só os dados que mudaram.

Um último motivo que consigo lembrar é quando você está interagindo com algo que só fornece esta API.

É interessante ter um mecanismo de *ping* para fechar uma conexão pelo servidor para não manter conexões abertas quando elas não está ativas. É comum o cliente não fechar a conexão. Tem várias técnicas para fazer o fechamento forçado mas já é outro assunto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Este é exatamente o mesmo ponto que desenvolvedores Client-Server, habituados com conexões permanentes, levantaram quando aplicações web dinâmicas começaram a se popularizar utilizando frameworks como *CGI*, *WebBase*, *ASP* e similares.

'Podemos fazer tudo com uma conexão permanente. Qual a vantagem de adicionar todo esse novo *overhead*?'

O interessante é que muitos dos pontos defendidos nesse passado distante podem ser utilizados para justificar a utilização de SignalR e similares:

- Você poupa o processo de todo o handshaking necessário para estabelecer uma conexão;

  - especialmente importante se você estiver rodando sob HTTPS/TLS/SSL (razão pela qual várias aplicações seguras solicitam *Keep-Alive*);
  - Menos *handshaking* significa menor tempo de resposta;
  - Menor quantidade de dados trafegada;
  - Aplicação mais responsiva.

Em resumo, conexões persistentes beneficiam qualquer aplicação que demande uma grande quantidade de dados para manter seu estado transacional ou que precise minimizar a latência entre servidor e cliente.